# Neo4j https communication

Tags: https, neo4j

Is there any way to allow only https, instead of http, for the communication with the Neo4j server? Also, which channel does the Neo4j Shell's communication use, http or https?

Comment: This might help You http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/security-server.html

Answer (score 1):

From http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/security-server.html:

HTTPS support
The Neo4j server includes built in support for SSL encrypted communication over HTTPS. The first time the server starts, it automatically generates a self-signed SSL certificate and a private key. Because the certificate is self signed, it is not safe to rely on for production use, instead, you should provide your own key and certificate for the server to use.

To provide your own key and certificate, replace the generated key and certificate, or change the neo4j-server.properties file to set the location of your certificate and key:

```
# Certificate location (auto generated if the file does not exist)
org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.cert.location=ssl/snakeoil.cert

# Private key location (auto generated if the file does not exist)
org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.key.location=ssl/snakeoil.key
Note that the key should be unencrypted. Make sure you set correct permissions on the private key, so that only the Neo4j server user can read/write it.
```

Neo4j also supports chained SSL certificates. This requires to have all certificates in PEM format combined in one file and the private key needs to be in DER format.

You can set what port the HTTPS connector should bind to in the same configuration file, as well as turn HTTPS off:

```
# Turn https-support on/off
org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.enabled=true

# https port (for all data, administrative, and UI access)
org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.port=443
```

About your second question: which channel does the Neo4j Shell's communication use, http or https? The default channel is http.

Answer (score 1):

This is from Neo4j Documentation:

**[HTTPS support](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/security-server.html#_https_support)**

The Neo4j server includes built in support for SSL encrypted communication over HTTPS. The first time the server starts, it automatically generates a self-signed SSL certificate and a private key. Because the certificate is self signed, it is not safe to rely on for production use, instead, you should provide your own key and certificate for the server to use.

To provide your own key and certificate, replace the generated key and certificate, or change the neo4j-server.properties file to set the location of your certificate and key:

```
# Certificate location (auto generated if the file does not exist)
org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.cert.location=ssl/snakeoil.cert

# Private key location (auto generated if the file does not exist)
org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.key.location=ssl/snakeoil.key
```

Note that the key should be unencrypted. Make sure you set correct permissions on the private key, so that only the Neo4j server user can read/write it.

Neo4j also supports chained SSL certificates. This requires to have all certificates in PEM format combined in one file and the private key needs to be in DER format.

You can set what port the HTTPS connector should bind to in the same configuration file, as well as turn HTTPS off:

```
# Turn https-support on/off
org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.enabled=true

# https port (for all data, administrative, and UI access)
org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.port=443
```

Comment: The question was, how to allow ONLY HTTPS? I commented out HTTP part in config file, and neo4j refused to start. It seems that http must be always available.