# Neo4j HTTPS only?

Tags: https, neo4j

there doesn't seem to exist any configuration that enables HTTPS only access to neo4j databases.

I've tried disabling the HTTP connectors but neo4j needs at least one HTTP connector otherwise it wouldn't start the service at all.

I found that commenting out the HTTP connector would let the neo4j service start but triggers an error in all browsers except chrome that wouldn't let you connect to the database.

Comment: This might be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23989334/neo4j-https-communication)

Comment: The practical solution is to allow access to (https) port 7473 and to (bolt) port 7687 and not to (http) port 7474 ... but it would seem that currently the server does indeed require the http to be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as my research has brought me. There is no neo4j-only solution to this problem at the moment.

From what I've read and found out there might be several possibilities like limiting http access to port 7474 from outside of your network and redirecting http to https. 
I was not able to test them personally but it seems that there's no different way to do this.

For now http has to be enabled and configured for https to work.